# JS/Jquery Random Position of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

This has been asked before and I got my code running.

The problem is with some weird viewport sizes the script seems to freeze.
There is nothing you can do but kill the tab.

I tried to script some backup that will kill the loop if its frozen, but it does not seem to get the job done.

Can anyone tell me whats wrong? Or show me an error in the script in general thats causing the freeze?

Thats the site where the code is running:
http://unkn0wn3d.com

JS Code is eithere there:
http://unkn0wn3d.com/css/pos.js

or here:

```
var pos = function(){
var containerW = $("article").width();
var containerH = $("article").height();
var langH = parseInt($( ".languages" ).position().top + $( ".languages" ).height());
var langW = parseInt($( ".languages" ).position().left + $( ".languages" ).width());
var creditW = parseInt($( ".credit" ).position().left - $(".link:first").width() + 15);
var positions = [];
var froze = false;
setTimeout(function(){froze=true;}, 2000)
$('.link').each(function() {
    var coords = {
        w: $(this).outerWidth(true)+5,
        h: $(this).outerHeight(true)+5
    };
    var success = false;
    while (!success)
    {
        coords.x = parseInt(Math.random() * (containerW-coords.w));
        coords.y = parseInt(Math.random() * (containerH-coords.h));
        var success = true;
        $.each(positions, function(){
            if (froze){return false;}
            if (
                (coords.x <= langW &&
                coords.y <= langH) ||
                (coords.x >= creditW &&
                coords.y <= langH) ||
                (coords.x <= (this.x + this.w) &&
                (coords.x + coords.w) >= this.x &&
                coords.y <= (this.y + this.h) &&
                (coords.y + coords.h) >= this.y)
            )
            {
                success = false;
            }
        });
    }
    positions.push(coords);
    $(this).css({
        top: coords.y + 'px',
        left: coords.x + 'px',
        display: 'block'
    });
})};

var waitForFinalEvent = (function () {
  var timers = {};
  return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
    if (!uniqueId) {
      uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId";
    }
    if (timers[uniqueId]) {
      clearTimeout (timers[uniqueId]);
    }
    timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

$(document).ready(
    pos()
);
$(window).resize(function () {
    waitForFinalEvent(function(){pos();}, 500, "resize");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems.  I don't see where you are doing it, but the size of your A.link elements is being controlled only by the height of the viewport.  So if the viewport is tall and narrow, then the links are large, and it's simply impossible to fit them all.

The second problem is that if the links can't be placed your code just keeps trying forever.  The timer will never fire because the main script is still busy running.  Rather than just do

```
while (!success)
```

it would be better to do a limited number of attempts:

```
var success = false;
for (var attempt = 0; !success && attempt < 50; attempt++)
{
     ....
}
```

By limiting the number of tries it will stop it freezing, even if the links are left overlapping.  Then you can remove froze and the timer.
Even better would be to introduce a tolerance as the number of attempts increases - so they are allowed to overlap a little bit.

Comment: That's great! The size of the postits is controlled by vmin to make sure that portrait devices wont get huge postits. If you create a thin and tall viewport you'll notice that the postits wont grow larger.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop never terminates since inside it you wrote `var success = true`
You redefined your *success* variable again by using var, so now you have 2 instances of *success* and the first one is never set to true so the loop never terminates. Try removing `var` from `var success = true`